# Suppressing GCC error output when invoking it from a C program

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'm trying to compile certain files from my C program in Linux and give them grades.
I'd like to give zero grade if the file did not compile. I already managed to do so, but I have a problem in this case, because gcc is printing a message to the screen (what is called the compilation error).

I've been googling and looked in the man for a flag which would prevent it from doing so, but haven't found one yet.

Does anyone know what is the flag?
Or else, maybe there's other solution?

Here's my code:

```
//child process
    if((pid=fork())==0)
    {
        execl("/usr/bin/gcc", "/usr/bin/gcc", "-o", outpath, fullpath,NULL);
    }
    else
    {
        wait(&stat);
        if(WIFEXITED(stat))
        {
            stat=WEXITSTATUS(stat);
            if(stat!=0)
            {
                if(write(fdresult,",0\r\n",4)==-1)
                {
                    perror("Writing result.csv has failed.");
                    exit(1);
                }
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Note:This code works. I just need a way to prevent gcc from printing an error when the file does not compile.

Thanks!

edit:
Tried adding

```
dup2("/dev/null",2);
```

just before execl, but gcc still print out message.

Comment: How about redirecting `stderr` to a file?

Comment: must it be to a file? I do not want to create a file just for that..

Comment: redirect to `/dev/null` - no new file will be created

Comment: You could redirect it to `/dev/nul` (or is it `/dev/null`?) instead.

Comment: added  dup2("/dev/null",2), still doesnt work

Comment: `dup2` doesn't work like you think it works. If in doubt, consult the man page.

Comment: I do suggest passing at least `-Wall` to the `fork`-ed `gcc` process, and of course to take into account both its *stderr* and *stdout* messages; I believe that ignoring them (e.g. by redirecting them to `/dev/null`) is probably a design mistake.

Comment: Read also http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C standard, the `freopen` function associates a given stream (`stderr`) with a file of a given path (`"/dev/null"`), specifying its mode (`"w"`).

```
#include <stdio.h>

freopen ("/dev/null", "w", stderr);
```